# How to get a return value and use in a string?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
m.shape
print("M have a:" + m.shape[1] + "rows and" + m.shape[2] + "columns")
```

I want use values in return of m.shape between the strings? How can I do it?

Comment: I think you would be better served by a general language tutorial than by asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to concatenate a string with the `+` operator, you need to convert the integers into strings using `str()`. Alternatively, you can print your desired output as follows, which won't require you to convert the integers.

`print("M has", m.shape[0], "rows and", m.shape[1], "columns")`

Secondly, Python uses zero-based indexing, such that m.shape[2] will throw a `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

The full working code would look as follows:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
print("M has", m.shape[0], "rows and", m.shape[1], "columns")
```

Comment: You don't even need `str`.

Comment: You can also remove the line: `m.shape`

Comment: In Python 3.6+ you could use an fstring as well `print(f"M have a: {m.shape[0]} rows and {m.shape[1]} columns")` or see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) for other string formatting options

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest 2 changes:

1. You may use a formatted string:

   *your print statement*:

   ```
   print("M have a:" + m.shape[1] + "rows and" + m.shape[2] + "columns")
   ```

   *suggested print statement*:

   ```
   print(f'M have a: {m.shape[1]} rows and {m.shape[2]} columns')
   ```
2. You need to change the indexes as m.shape returns a tuple which starts with index 0

   ```
   print(f'M have a: {m.shape[0]} rows and {m.shape[1]} columns')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do it (by my taste):

```
import numpy as np
s = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3).shape
print(f'M have a: {s[0]} rows and {s[1]} columns')
```

Remark: indexes starts from 0.

And a happy thing, f - strings are [pretty new](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) in pythonworld.